# При помощи awk/регулярных выражений получить все строки где мин.цена > 10

Tags: awk

Есть определенный текстовый документ

```
                                          Мин цена
100890!ACE TENNIS NET              !58    !46.4  !01-JAN-89
100860!ACE TENNIS RACKET I         !35    !28    !01-JUN-90
100861!ACE TENNIS RACKET II        !45    !36    !01-JUN-90
100870!ACE TENNIS BALLS-3 PACK     !2.8   !2.4   !01-JAN-90
100871!ACE TENNIS BALLS-6 PACK     !5.6   !4.8   !01-JAN-90
101860!SP TENNIS RACKET            !24    !18    !15-FEB-89
101863!SP JUNIOR RACKET            !12.5  !9.4   !15-FEB-89
102130!RH: "GUIDE TO TENNIS"       !3.4   !2.8   !18-AUG-89
200376!SB ENERGY BAR-6 PACK        !2.4   !1.75  !15-NOV-90
200380!SB VITA SNACK-6 PACK        !4     !3.2   !15-NOV-90
103120!WIFF SOFTBALL BAT I         !25    !20    !01-JUN-90
103121!WIFF SOFTBALL BAT II        !30    !24    !01-JUN-90
103130!WIFF SOFTBALL, SMALL        !4.2   !3.6   !01-JAN-90
103131!WIFF SOFTBALL, LARGE        !4.5   !3.9   !01-JAN-90
103140!WIFF SOFTBALL MITT (LH)     !20    !15    !15-FEB-89
103141!WIFF SOFTBALL MITT (RH)     !20    !15    !15-FEB-89
102132!RH: "GUIDE TO SOFTBALL"     !3.4   !2.8   !18-AUG-89
104350!DUNK BASKETBALL INDOOR      !44    !35.3  !01-JUN-90
104351!DUNK BASKETBALL OUTDOOR     !26    !20.8  !01-JUN-90
104352!DUNK BASKETBALL PROFESSIONAL!58.3  !40.8  !01-JUN-90
104360!DUNK HOOP                   !39    !32    !01-JAN-90
104361!DUNK HOOP W/FIBERGLASS BOARD!50    !35    !01-JAN-90
104362!DUNK NETS - RAINBOW         !5     !4     !15-FEB-89
102134!RH: "GUIDE TO BASKETBALL"   !3.4   !2.8   !18-AUG-89
105123!YELLOW JERSEY BICYCLE HELMET!40    !34    !01-JUN-90
105124!YELLOW JERSEY BICYCLE GLOVES!15    !10    !01-JUN-90
105125!YELLOW JERSEY WATER BOTTLE  !3     !2.6   !01-JAN-90
105126!YELLOW JERSEY BOTTLE CAGE   !6     !5     !01-JAN-90
105127!YELLOW JERSEY FRAME PUMP    !6     !5     !15-NOV-90
105128!YELLOW JERSEY SADDLE PACK   !10    !8     !15-NOV-90
102136!RH: "GUIDE TO CYCLING"      !3.4   !2.8   !18-AUG-89%
```

Задача: При помощи коносольной утилиты awk/регулярных выражений получить все строки где мин цена > 10

Comment: попробуйте `awk -F'!' '{if ($4 > 10) {print $0}}' /youfile.txt`

Comment: Спасибо! И ваш и другой способ верны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это же самые простые примеры на которых учишься при изучении awk

```
awk -F! '$4>10' FILE
```